# how to make non copyable html page like google book

Tags: google-books

I am just curious if I can be able to copy books from google or not.And I am also curious to know what to make such kind of material.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose the best way is to convert the text pages to images.  You'd still be able to capture the images, but they wouldn't be in text form anymore; to get them back in their original form, you'd have to OCR them, which is an arduous process.

Comment: well, i researched a bit and of course it was an png image, but could you explain what is OCR